# How can I optimize this VERY slow MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance, subquery, taxonomy

I have a WordPress-based site which catalogs scholarly articles for a regional science journal.

Simply said, the system has several thousand "Posts", and each has a "pub_type" Taxonomy in which only 1 Term is selected: "Manuscript", or something else.

Each Post also has a variety of other Taxonomies/Terms it is related to.

---

**Objective:** Get a list of terms for a particular Taxonomy. For each term, Count the number of Posts related to it, AND determine how many of those Posts have "Manuscript" set within the "pub_type" Taxonomy.

---

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT term_id, term_id as term_id_b, name, slug,
( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN 
    ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN 
        ( SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = term_id_b ) 
) AND post_status = "publish" ) as count,
( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM wp_posts WHERE id IN 
    ( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN 
        ( SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id IN 
            ( SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id = term_id_b ) 
        )
    ) 
AND id IN 
( SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN
    ( SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = 
        ( SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name = "Manuscript" ) 
    AND taxonomy = "pub_type" )
)
AND post_status = "publish"
) as manuscript_count
FROM wp_terms 
WHERE term_id IN 
( SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = "'.$taxonomy.'" )
ORDER BY name ASC
```

---

While this query *does work*, it runs extremely slow... as in between 3-5 minutes depending on server load. It's so bad that, in order to maintain site performance, I've had to cache the query results to a JSON text file and only let the query run every 2 hours.

I know that the main problem here is that I've used sub-queries for everything. While I am trying to learn more about working with joins, I don't yet know enough to write this query any other way.

Can anyone offer some insights or suggestions as to how I can tame this beast?

**edit:** Here is a screenshot of the EXPLAIN output from the query:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezq65.png

Comment: A lot of the time for subqueries, `WHERE EXISTS` is faster than `WHERE IN`.  However, to give you a better answer, I would need to see the query plan.  Could you add the `EXPLAIN PLAN` output to your question?

Comment: If I wanted to go there, I wouldn't start from here. :-( Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Are you saying you want to do this: Count the number of posts that have each term for the pub_type taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

See [this great post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/) about the use of `IN` and how it can negatively affect query speed. This has your problem written all over it.

Essentially, with a traditional `IN(values)` query, you are simply searching for each value. In a subquery `IN` as you have (`IN(SELECT)`).

In it, the author quotes from MySQL's manual:

> If the inner and outer queries return M and N rows, respectively, the execution time becomes on the order of O(MxN), rather than O(M+N) as it would be for an uncorrelated subquery.

Using this logic, you have `wp_posts` at as an outer query, and within it nested `wp_terms_relationship` at 10 rows, and within *that* nested, `wp_terms` again. That one is `949*(10*1))`. The second time around you have only two levels of nesting, but because the final level only has one row, it is still the same impact: You are ending up parsing through 9490 rows.

Subqueries are not your friend. While sometimes they may be necessary, they can almost always be solved using `JOIN`. This does not seem like it is much different based on your objectives. By rewriting this query and stretching to attempt to use `JOIN...ON`, you will find that after a brief learning curve it will be *much* easier to read your own code, follow its logical progression, and, most likely, see it speed up too. At the very least, utilize `join`s where you can. You will thank yourself later.